# How do I parse non-English date strings in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, locale

I'm trying to parse some non-English datetime strings in Python. I've had success with Western European languages such as French, Spanish and Italian. However, for Czech, Finnish and Greek I have been unsuccessful.

I am setting the locale as follows:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ell')
```

I've been unable to find any code examples online, or any documentation. Is there somewhere that the datetime model details what languages are supported?

I am running on Windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Locales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale) tend to use a combination of [2-digit ISO-639 language codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639) and [2-digit ISO-3166 country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). Your example uses 'ell' for what I assume should be Greek; try `el_GR` instead. Similarly, Czech would be `cs_CZ` and Finnish `fi_FI`.

Comment: I tried this and got "Error: unsupported locale setting". If you look at the wikipedia article's section on Windows it points to this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28vs.71%29.aspx, which is where I got the 'ell' from.